# How is Windows checking its users are online?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I'm using the `ActiveDirectory` library in c# to pull user and group details etc.

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

I googled how to find if a user is online but apparently there's no way to do this using ActiveDirectory so I'm left wondering, how is Windows seeing who's online? e.g. on Outlook, SharePoint or Skype, we see a user's status (red, green, yellow - busy, available, away etc.)

Is there a way to do this building on any info I can get from ActiveDirectory?

Comment: Is it in Asp.Net ?

Comment: Yeah, asp.net using framework 4.7.2

Comment: "Presence" is the term you're looking for and unfortunately it's separately implemented in different places. The [presence API for Teams](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35689261-blynclight-for-microsoft-teams) has recently gone into Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> e.g. on Outlook, SharePoint or Skype, we see a user's status (red, green, yellow - busy, available, away etc.)

If your organization uses Skype for Business, then that is how it's doing it. As long as the user has Skype for Business open and logged in, then they will show online to others who have Skype for Business open and logged in. Outlook uses the status from SfB.

To verify this, you can close your SfB, and you will see that Outlook no longer shows you the status of other people.